# How to load fb all.js script on a Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to load asynchronously the connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js script , see [here](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/157155/latest/)

The problem is that fbAsyncInit is never get called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because 'window' in a content script is not the real window, but a proxy. I can get your code working by replacing window with 'unsafeWindow':

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/157253/latest/

Note that this introduces a possible security issue - in particular you should not trust any data that comes form unsafeWindow or anything attached to it. This is a hack that can be used to get things working in cases where the the proxy will not, but could be used to allow web pages to execute arbitrary code with the privileges of the browser.

Comment: Thank you. The problem now is that when I am using FB.init I get the error that "FB is not defined" as you may see on the link I provided (this has worked as a chrome extension).However I see that the script is added on the document by inspecting the page.

Comment: That's because FB is defined in the real window, not in the scoep of the content script. You can reach it by again using unsafeWindow.FB.init(...) but I'd be very careful about what code you run in FB.init.